# React js - Add unique key for ant design switch

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am having a problem on how to add a unique key to the switch that is under my loop.

Actual Output: Whenever I click one switch, all switches are toggling too.

Expected Result: One switch must toggle depends on what switch I selected and not the other switches

here is my code:

```
  let keys;
  let output = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    keys = {
      ...info[i],
      key: i,
      actionIndex: (
        <div>
            <Switch 
            checked={isSwitchToggle ? true: false}
            onClick={()=> {
              handleSwitch(
                info[i],
                handleChangeSwitch,
              )
            }} />
        </div>
      ),
    };

    output.push(keys);
  }
  return output;
```

Here is the function that toggle the `isSwitchToggle` state

```
handleChangeSwitch = () => {
        const { isSwitchToggle } = this.state
        this.setState({ 
            isSwitchToggle: !isSwitchToggle, 
    })
}
```

Im using Ant design switch by the way. Thanks for the help

Comment: You would need multiple state variables.

Comment: did you try the field decorator, and initial value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to handle an individual [switch](https://ant.design/components/switch/). Do change the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-59962894-multiple-antd-switch) as per your demand.

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    let info = [
      { id: 1, name: "a", isSwitchToggle: true },
      { id: 2, name: "b", isSwitchToggle: false },
      { id: 3, name: "c", isSwitchToggle: true }
    ];
    let output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      output.push(<SingleSW data={info[i]} />);
    }

    let switches =
      output.length !== 0 && output.map((row, i) => <div key={i}>{row}</div>);

    return <div>{switches}</div>;
  }
}
```

**SingleSW** (Single switch [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components))

```
const SingleSW = ({ data }) => {
  const [switchToggle, setSwitchToggle] = useState(data.isSwitchToggle);

  const onChange = checked => {
    setSwitchToggle(checked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Switch checked={switchToggle} onChange={onChange} />
      <span> {data.name}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```