# React Hook "useState" is called in function "deviceStatus" which is neither a React function component or a custom React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am new to react hooks and functional components, i am trying to user useState inside my functional component its showing me the error as mentions

Using React, ant design

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './device-status.css'

import { Checkbox, Switch } from "antd";

function deviceStatus() {

    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false)

    const toggleSwitch = (checked) => {
        console.log(checked);

        setIsEnabled(checked)
    }
   return (
         <div className="devicestatus-item" >
              <span>Front Low Light :</span>
               <Switch checked={isEnabled} onChange={toggleSwitch} />
          </div>
    )
}
export default deviceStatus
```

Reference followed
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962894/react-js-add-unique-key-for-ant-design-switch)

**Error :**

React Hook "useState" is called in function "deviceStatus" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused because React read functional component with Pascal case. So, try change your function and file name  into `DeviceStatus`